# Fancy Box in Google Chrome

Tags: jquery, jsp, fancybox

I am using spring Framework, java and jsp in my app.I am using Fancy box for a pop up in my application. wherever required i call it using a class. It works fine with Mozilla Firefox, but in Google Chrome, multiple pop up forms loads like a slide show on scroll. 
what could be done to avoid multiple forms ?

```
         $(".feedbackPopup").fancybox({
                'width'             : '38%',
                'height'            : '65%',
                'min-height'        : 180,
                'autoScale'     : false,
                'transitionIn'      : 'none',
                'transitionOut'     : 'none',
                'hideOnOverlayClick' : false,
                'type'          : 'iframe'
            });

         $(".registerPopup").fancybox({
                'width'         : '40%',
                'height'        : '70%',
                'min-height'        : 180,
                'autoScale'     : false,
                'transitionIn'      : 'none',
                'transitionOut'     : 'none',
                'hideOnOverlayClick' : false,
                'type'              : 'iframe'
            });
        });
</script>
```

I have 3 icons namely feedback,login, & register on the menu bar of my app.,I use the following syntax to call

```
<div class="feedback">
 <a rel="tooltip" title="Feedback"  href="doFwdController.html"  class="txtdark_link feedbackPopup"><img src="images/feedback-icon.png" border="0" /></a>
</div>
<div class="login">
 <a  class="txtdark_link loginPopup" rel="tooltip" title="Login"  href="doLogin.html" ><img src="images/login-icon.png" border="0"  /></a>
</div>
```

similarly for register..It works absolutely fine for firefox browser...But when I use the same on chrome..ex:If I call login at first & scroll the form, the other two get called simultaneously & becomes a slideshow of 3 forms..How to prevent this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Elements are bound to a fancybox gallery when they share the same `rel` attribute. Unless you have an specific use for `rel="tooltip"`, you can try removing it.